# Slurp standard-input into a buffer

Tags: script, pipe

How do I read the entire contents of stdin into an Emacs buffer in `#! /usr/bin/env emacs --script` mode? Stdin may not be a regular file.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/31404/how-to-make-emacs-read-buffer-from-stdin-on-start

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, apparently this is the best we can do right now:

```
#! /usr/bin/env emacs --script

(defun slurp-stdin ()
  (condition-case nil (while t (insert (read-from-minibuffer "") "\n"))
    (error)))

(with-temp-buffer
  (slurp-stdin)
  (princ (buffer-string)))
```

- It abuses a gimmick of `read-from-minibuffer` that causes that function to read a line from stdin when Emacs is in batch mode.
- There's no fundamental reason to read a line at a time instead of chunk-at-a-time, but I can't find a chunk-at-a-time read function in Emacs.
- It cannot distinguish between different kinds of newlines (CR or CR/LF) and cannot differentiate between the presence or lack of a final newline at the end of stdin. I'm not sure what kind of newline conversion (if any) is done.
- It cannot distinguish between end-of-file and other errors. Emacs has an `end-of-file` condition type that is used for that purpose by `read`, but `read-from-minibuffer` does not use it.
- On the bright side, it works fine with pipes and sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Read `/dev/stdin`, e.g.,

```
$ date -u | emacs --batch --eval '(insert-file-contents "/dev/stdin")' --eval '(princ (buffer-string))'
Thu Nov 28 19:12:02 UTC 2019
```

Not sure about Windows though.